# Can I choose ClientAccessPolicy.xml OR CrossDomain.xml for silverlitght?

Tags: silverlight

Do I need to use both CrossDomain.xml (CD) and ClientAccessPolicy.xml (CAP) in all of my Silverlight projects?  Could I use one instead of the other?

As I undertand it, CrossDomain.xml was created for Flash, and ClientAccessPolicy.xml was created for Silverlight.  So CAP provides special access such as sockets for WCF.

But what if you don't use WCF sockets?  Can you get by with just CrossDomain?  Or should you always ditch CrossDomain in favor of CAP if your site is pure ASP.NET and Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this page http://www.devtoolshed.com/explanation-cross-domain-and-client-access-policy-files-silverlight